# How to store POINTS(LANG, LAT) into geometry type column in PostGIS?

Tags: database, postgresql, types, postgis

I have created a table `itapp_cities` in PostGIS which stores the data of cities. I have added a column `location` with datatype `geometry` to store `longitude` and `latitude` of a city. When I run the following `INSERT` query I get the error shown below.

**`INSERT` query:**

```
INSERT INTO itapp_cities(city_id, city_name, city_code, state_id, location) 
  VALUES (DEFAULT,'Ada', 'ada-ok',37,POINT(34.774531000000003, -96.678344899999999));
```

**Table definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE itapp_cities
(
  city_id bigserial NOT NULL,
  city_name character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  city_code character varying(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::character varying,
  state_id bigint NOT NULL,
  location geometry,
  CONSTRAINT itapp_cities_pkey PRIMARY KEY (city_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_states FOREIGN KEY (city_id)
      REFERENCES itapp_states (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

**Error:**

> ```
> ERROR:  column "location" is of type geometry but expression is of type point
> LINE 2:   VALUES (DEFAULT,'Ada', 'ada-ok',37,POINT(34.77453100000000...
>                                              ^
> HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: column "location" is of type geometry but expression is of type point
> SQL state: 42804
> ```

How can I store point values inside this column? I am new to PostGIS so forgive me for this silly question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function [**`ST_MakePoint()`**](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) and the set the [SRID (Spatial Reference System Identifier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRID) with [`ST_SetSRID()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SetSRID.html):

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude),4326)
```

Or while you enter literal values anyway, feed the string representation to [**`ST_GeomFromText()`**](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html):

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(34.774531 -96.6783449)')
```

Related answer on dba.SE with more details and links:

- [Order by distance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60711/3684)

Answer (score 2):

Try this SQL and match it with your insert sql query

```
    INSERT INTO itapp_cities(city_id, city_name, slug, state_id, location) 
  VALUES (DEFAULT,'Ada', 'ada-ok',37,st_GeomFromText('POINT(34.774531000000003 -96.678344899999999)', 312));
```

for more details go through this [link](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.3/ch04.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the postGIS docs, your original insert was close.  Just add ' around the POINT expression.

```
INSERT INTO itapp_cities(city_id, city_name, city_code, state_id, location) 
  VALUES (DEFAULT,'Ada', 'ada-ok',37,'POINT(34.774531000000003, -96.678344899999999)');
```

http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geometries.html