# PostgreSQL 15 - PostGIS - store tuple of Point Coordinates in single column

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Currently within my SQL Server database I am storing 'city areas' as VARCHAR strings:

E.g would fit the following in a cell:

> "[[34.4577966, -119.7706809], [33.7391024, -118.1501976], [33.3637118,
> -117.5239769], [32.5895493, -117.3262229], [32.5849209, -115.8320824], [33.958085, -116.2220969], [34.9860451, -116.925222], [35.5022797,
> -119.0473803], [34.4577966, -119.7706809]]"

With PostgreSQL (with PostGIS extension) I want to store the following data in a PostGIS column.

I know how to store single points i.e:

```
CREATE TABLE cities(
    city_id serial not null Primary key unique,
)

ALTER TABLE cities ADD COLUMN city_bounds geometry(Point, 4326);
```

But how can I store a list of Points?

Googling "storing list of points in PostGIS only gives me recommended answers to store **[single](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33207930/how-to-store-pointslang-lat-into-geometry-type-column-in-postgis)** points but I am looking to store a list of points in a column

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a MULTIPOINT geometry type.

Comment: From the description (city areas), a `polygon` should be used. From the column name (city bounds), it could also be a `linestring`. And since the 1st and last points are the same, it would be surprising to store points directly

Comment: @JGH can it just be a simple POLYGON or does it need to be a POLYGON of POINT objects?

Comment: The object is a polygon, which under the hood is composed of multiple points. `POLYGON((-119.7706809 34.4577966,-118.1501976 33.7391024,-117.5239769 33.3637118,-117.3262229 32.5895493,-115.8320824 32.5849209,-116.2220969 33.958085,-116.925222 34.9860451,-119.0473803 35.5022797,-119.7706809 34.4577966))`